# iOS11 image rendering issues

Tags: css, angularjs, iphone, image, ios11

On IPhone devices with iOS11 I am having issues with rendering of images. What I am doing is lazyloading a list of images on scroll but randomly some images fail to render. I have tried debugging on Safari desktop and it shows that img tag does have src set on it but still it doesn't render till I do some action which opens any layer completely covering the area.

Things I've tried:-

1. transform3d to use GPU rendering. Using opacity, will-change aswell.
2. Adding some styling to element through JS to trigger reflow/redraw

*One Doubt*: Does it have to do anything with PPI(Pixel Per Inch). Currently its 150PPI. Do I need to reduce it to 72PPI?.

I would have given the link where the issue is actually happening but cannot really sorry

Fiddle Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/y37eL2hp/4/

Fullscreen : http://fiddle.jshell.net/y37eL2hp/4/show/light/

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
  <div ng-controller="Mycontroller">
    <div class="my-product" ng-repeat="product in products track by $index">
      <div class="my-productimgblk">
            <ng-lazy-load-img imgsrc="product" class="lazy-smooth-load my-productimg" elem-type="img" elem-width="309" elem-height="400" load-offset-top="860"></ng-lazy-load-img>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I checked above example and its having same issue. Do clear cache on reload

Comment: Can you please set up a jsfiddle just to illustrate the issue?

Comment: can you also add some code, at least the elements surrounding the img tag

Comment: Could you try running your site through: https://tools.pingdom.com and screen shotting the 'file requests' water fall.  As you are using lazyload if there is a file that's taking a long time to load it might be blocking the rendering of your image.

Comment: Also one things that will slow down the loading of the images is having lots of images which are over 72ppi and not resized!!!

Comment: I've resolved the issue. So what was happening was in angularjs, src is set later. When I checked in other sites where its working they were adding the img tag to DOM when needed for lazyloading images. So I did the same and now its working. But I still want an answer like how iOS renders images. Is it doing any kind of rendering optimizations? It happened to me on a page with large list of images other pages were working fine.

Comment: I am having a very similar issue, I think it is a bug in iOS 11.

Comment: Fiddle added. Please check

Comment: @Zword cheers for that - I'm not sure if this is the answer as I can't test on IOS11 at the moment but I ran it through pingdom and this was the file that was taking the longest to load: https://rawgit.com/JesselJohn/ngResourceLoader/master/src/imageloader.js

 When I looked at the code you seem to be using the variables before they've been defined, so that that the parser searches all the code i.e you could use var i = 0; before using i++

Comment: @ColinGell dont see any i++ in my code

Comment: https://rawgit.com/JesselJohn/ngResourceLoader/master/src/imageloader.js

Comment: Thats written by me only and I dont see any i++

Comment: Its not related to JS because we had another JS lazyload used before this and had same issue. Also like I mentioned img src is getting set its just not rendering if img tag is present and you set src later like we normally do in angularjs using ng-src. It only works if you add img along with src value then it loads correctly

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is a known issue which is believed to related to Safari assumes obscure mono-wide square characters, and once the font is loaded it times out your javascript inlcuding your lazyload script.

The workaround solution is to include a fallback font which is common i.e

```
font-family: "Your strange font", Arial, Sans-Serif;
```

or perhaps use google-fonts

Hopefully though the IOS11 system will get patched soon!!!

For more information see this link: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=174031

Comment: I have added a fiddle example. I am not using any font there but still same issue

Comment: This seems to be unrelated to OPs question.

Answer (score 0):

It's back to hacks again with iOS11 it seems. We needed hacks like this in the past with `-webkit` but now we need it again but unprefixed...

```
img {
    transform: rotateZ(360deg);
}
```